# Javascript+Canvas implementation of Game of Life not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having problems with my javascript+canvas implementation of Conways Game of Life.
The cells are being created just fine and the canvas boxed representing the cells are also being rendered fine. But somewhere along the way all cells seems to be set alive & aren't toggling.
For the life of me I can't understand what's wrong.
The javascript code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/elssar/FTkfC) and my implementation is [here](http://www.justarandomguy.com).
Can someone please tell me where I went wrong.

***************************************EDIT*********************************************

I think I've figured out whats wrong. I'm passing an element of the 2d array to the reallyToggle() function, like so -

```
var reallyToggle = function(a) {
//code
}
reallyToggle(cell[i][j]);
```

I think the problem lies in this part of the code. Can anyone tell me how can I pass an element of an array to a function?

Comment: The links don't exist. Could you fix that? And I think this is a Game Development Question. Therefore, you should ask it here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @fireDude links fixed. Don't think it really qualifies as a game dev question & would probably be shifted back to stackoverflow

Comment: Yeah this isn't so much a game as it is an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code is pretty obscure and overly-complicated to be honest. Creating a grid of custom Javascript function objects is way over-engineering: all you need is a 2D boolean array.

Problems like this are often easiest to solve if thought of as two separate problems: the problem space and the world space. The problem space is the area in which you solve the actual problem. The world space is the problem space mapped to a visual outcome. To separate it out for your problem, think of the problem space as the two dimensional array of booleans and then the world space is your canvas.

If you would like to clean up your simulation a bit, here is an approach that may help:

```
//Have some parameters that you can change around
var cellSize = 10;
var cellsWide = 100;
var cellsHigh = 100;

//Instantiate and initialize a 2d array to false
var theGrid = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<cellsWide; i++) {
    theGrid.push(new Array());
    for (var j=0; j<cellsHeight; j++) {
        theGrid[i].push(false);
    }
}

//Attach a click event to your canvas (assuming canvas has already been dropped on page
//at the assigned width/height
$('#simCanvas').click(function(e) {
    var i = Math.floor((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)/cellSize);
    var j = Math.floor((e.pageY - this.offsetTop)/cellSize);
    theGrid[i][j] = !theGrid[i][j];
});
```

This would be a much more succinct way for you to handle the problem space. The mapping of problem space to world space is a bit more straight-forward, but if you need help with that just let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have things like neighbours alive count associated with the cell object? With your implementation you would either create another double array to keep track of alive neighbours(which is basically the same thing) or calculate the alive neighbours on the fly every time you run the game loop. Surely the latter isn't advisable.

Comment: Considering this is a static, non "animated" simulation that only needs to calculate this once or twice a second (depending on how quickly you're doing the loop) I wouldn't worry about ~(height * width * 4) boolean checks. With 1000 height and width you're only talking about 4000000 inexpensive operations happening once or twice a second, which is not in any way a constraint. Always better to keep it simple if the hardware allows.

Answer (score 1):

This line is rather suspect :)

```
if (!run) run == true;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check MoarCodePlz answer. And about Your code:

`Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: gameLoop` when pressing start.
All Your functions that are defined in `initialize` are not in global scope, so they are not reachable in global scope.

Please, use Firebug; Chrome Developer Tools, Opera Dragonfly or something to find out such errors. These tools really help while developing JS.

Comment: Yeah, I had defined gameLoop & the other functions outside initialze but when it wasn't working I tried to put them inside initialize to see if it would work. Thanks for clearing that up.